# Loading .h5 file on .net core

Tags: python, c#, keras, .net-core

Context:
I am practising machine learning by creating a digit classifier.
the model was built on Jupyter notebook and exported to a .h5 file (mnist.h5)

I want to essentially replicate the python script i put together below (in c#) in order to utilise the model on a .net core application:

```
from keras import models
from PIL import Image 

model = models.load_model('mnist.h5')

img = Image.open('output.jpeg')

img = img.resize((28,28))
#convert rgb to grayscale
img = img.convert('L')
img = np.array(img)
#reshaping to support our model input and normalizing
img = img.reshape(1,28,28,1)
img = img/255
#predicting the class
res = model.predict([img])[0]

pred_value = np.argmax(res)
accuracy = max(res)

print(pred_value, accuracy)
```

What Ive tried so far:

Implemented IronPython nuget package to run the script:

```
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

        var script = $"{rootDirectory}\\Controllers\\MLModel\\RunModel.py";
        var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(script);

        // Output redirect 

        var eIO = engine.Runtime.IO;

        var errors = new MemoryStream();
        eIO.SetErrorOutput(errors, Encoding.Default);


        var result = new MemoryStream();
        eIO.SetOutput(result, Encoding.Default);

        // Execute Script

        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        source.Execute(scope);

        // Extract

        string str(byte[] x) => Encoding.Default.GetString(x);

        var e = str(errors.ToArray());
        var r = str(result.ToArray());
```

The problem i had with this was that the package 'Keras' was not found when program was executed. however The .py script will work outside of the .net core solution so running a pip install for keras will not work for me.

i also feel this will open doors to more problems, on the other hand i could be missing something so if there is any solution to this as well, please let me know.

I guess my question is can this be done? If so how? If not then what can i do instead?

Thank you.

Comment: I want to ask "what have you tried", but SO doesn't allow that question any more.   You need to show us how far you have got, not 'please do this for me'.

Comment: Hi @Neil i have edited the question to explain what i have tried. the aim is to pass the image.jpeg file to the model which will then output a result for me to utilise. i haven't gotten passed this stage and i am still actively searching for more solutions. i will update the question if i have tried any other methods. thank you.